# How do I get past turtle.Turtle?

Tags: python

Im creating a pong game as a beginner in python and can't get past a "turtle.Turtle" error

I typed,
ball = turtle.Turtle()

I get,
line 2, in 
ball = turtle.Turtle()
^^^^^^
NameError: name 'turtle' is not defined. Did you mean: 'tuple'?

Comment: first you need to import it. try to add `import turtle` before initializing `ball`

Comment: I gave you the answer did you see it